# Allow DELETE requests with message body, using Grizzly servlet container

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, grizzly

I was testing my REST API through Postman, with some dummy requests and I noticed when a DELETE request accidently had a message body, the server always returned with status code 400 (and no message). I know GET and DELETE requests should not have payloads, but I would prefer if the message body would be just ignored, or I could return my custom error message with the help of a `ContainerRequestFilter`. (The `Bad Request` is returned before I could parse the request with the RequestFilter)

The weird thing is, that I already configured Grizzly to allow this with `server.getServerConfiguration().setAllowPayloadForUndefinedHttpMethods(true);` (before starting the server), and as I can remember, in the past this worked. I'm not sure what changed... I'm still using this dependency for Jersey in my parent `pom.xml`:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
```

`<jersey.version>2.23.1</jersey.version>` and in child modules:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I've searched my project and I do not touch the `ServerConfiguration` anywhere else.

I changed my JSON provider, maybe that has something to do with it? I went from the Grizzly default Moxy to a customized Jackson JSON provider. I can show the custom `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`, if needed. What could override `setAllowPayloadForUndefinedHttpMethods(true)` here?

Comment: Did you create the server with the `false` parameter to tell it not to start immediately?

Comment: Which parameter is this? After calling the setAllowPayloadForUndefinedHttpMethods(true), I just use server.start() right after.
The uri and ResourceConfig is passed before that, with GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(...)

Comment: `GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(...) ` has an overload where you can pass a boolean parameter at the end. This is the parameter that tells the server not to start immediately if false is passed. It defaults to true.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha yeah I just found it, but I used the (URI, ResourceConfig) version, which has that parameter on true by default.

Comment: Yea, you want it false.

Comment: Good to know about this feature, thanks :) Wanna write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the server, you need to create in a way that it will not start immediately, otherwise you will not be able to configure it. To do this, just use the overload of `GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(...)` that allows you to pass a `boolean` as the last parameter. A value of `false` tells the server not to start immediately.

```
HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
                           URI.create(BASE_URI), resourceConfig, false);
server.getServerConfiguration().setAllowPayloadForUndefinedHttpMethods(true);
server.start();
```